# why would PostgreSQL connection establishment be CPU-bound

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda

I have a C# backend running on AWS Lambda. It connects to a PostgreSQL DB in the same region.

I observed extremely slow cold-startup execution time after adding the DB connection code. After allocating more memory to my Lambda function, the execution time has significantly reduced.

The execution time as measured by Lambda console:

- 128 MB (~15.5 sec)
- 256 MB (~9 sec)
- 384 MB (~6 sec)
- 512 MB (~4.5 sec)
- 640 MB (~3.5 sec)
- 768 MB (~3 sec)

In contrast, after commenting out the DB connection code:

- 128 MB (~5 sec)
- 256 MB (~2.5 sec)

So opening a DB connection has contributed a lot to the execution time.

According to AWS documentation:

> In the AWS Lambda resource model, you choose the amount of memory you
>   want for your function, and are allocated proportional CPU power and
>   other resources.

Since the peak memory usage has consistently stayed at ~45 MB, this phenomenon seems to suggest that database connection establishment is a computationally intensive activity. If so, why?

Code in question (I'm using [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/)):

```
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Db.connStr);
conn.Open();
using(conn)
{ // print something }
```

**Update 1**

I set up a MariaDB instance with the same configuration and did some testing.

Using [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) for synchronous operation:

- 128 MB (~12.5 sec)
- 256 MB (~6.5 sec)

Using [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/) for asynchronous operation:

- 128 MB (~11 sec)
- 256 MB (~5 sec)

Interestingly, the execution time on my laptop has increased from ~4 sec (for Npgsql) to 12~15 sec (for MySql.Data and MySqlConnector).

At this point, I'll just allocate more memory to the Lambda function to solve this issue. But if anyone knows why the connection establishment took so long, I'd appreciate an answer. I might post some profiling results later.

Comment: One possible contributor to CPU demand might be TLS negotiation, which you could presumably verify by temporarily disabling it (or confirming that you already aren't using TLS).  Your high-level observations are definitely correct, though -- increasing memory available increases CPU capacity pretty much linearly, so you are indeed CPU bound on *something*.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the comment. I've tried disabling SSL/TLS, that decreased the execution time by 1 second under the 128 MB configuration. So it is something but not _that_ much. In comparison, running the same code on my laptop takes about 4 seconds in total (note that the round-trip to AWS server takes more time, as Lambda code runs in the same region). Right now I think the best solution is to just scale up the memory, but I'm still curious why this is the case. I'll test with MySQL and a different library later, but I don't think that will change anything.